# IOS (change universal to ipad) my mistake i have upload build for iphone Now we want in new version this app is only for ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

IOS my mistake i have upload build for iphone   Now we want in new version this app is only for  ipad

change universal to ipad

A: iTunes Connect does not allow uploading an updated version of an app when the update runs on fewer devices than the version of the app currently in the App Store. This is by design.

An update to an app must work for every customer who has already purchased the app, and is running a current version of iOS.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC1IA.jpg)

Comment: What is your question?  You cannot make the new version more restrictive.  You can release a new app with a new bundle ID that is iPad only.

Answer (score 0):

From below Image, [image]

if you uploaded the app in set device iPhone, and now you want to change it to iPad, and trying to upload with new version then this error will occured, What you have to do is, set the device universal and upload, in these case iTunes show the app for iphone too, if some thing isn't supported in iPhone but in supported in iPad then the chance of rejection will increase during review period (You must be care full here), else, you have to hide the app from all territory in the app store and upload with a new bundle id with your chosen  supported Device.
Thanks